# How to extract time_created key from VM using ComputeManagementClient method

Tags: python, virtual-machine

I have a python script which pulls a list of VMs that exist in a specific RG of a subscription.

Printing the vm provides raw json data that helps me see that time_created in this data.
I need to extract this, but I haven't been successful.

Here is the script:

```
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential 
import json

subscription_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
resource_group_name = "myResourceGroup"
CREDENTIAL = DefaultAzureCredential(exclude_shared_token_cache_credential=True, exclude_environment_credential=True, exclude_managed_identity_credential=True, exclude_visual_studio_code_credential=True)

compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(CREDENTIAL, subscription_id)

for vm in compute_client.virtual_machines.list(resource_group_name):
   print(vm)
   for time_created in vm:
      list = time_created
      date = time_created['datetime.datetime']
      print(date)
```

I get the error:
for time_created in vm:
TypeError: 'VirtualMachine' object is not iterable

The example of the raw data looks like this:
{'additional_properties': {}, 'id': '/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/vm-0', 'name': 'vm-0', 'type': 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', 'location': 'eastus2', 'tags': {'OwnerEmail': 'hello@gmail.com', 'VMCreatedOn': '2022-12-21', 'SCRequestID': '111', 'LastDeployment': '2023-01-18T10:35:06.9845082Z'}, 'plan': None, 'resources': [<azure.mgmt.compute.v2023_09_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachineExtension object at 0x00000177654B5D90>, <azure.mgmt.compute.v2023_09_01.models._models_py3.VirtualMachineExtension object at 0x00000177654B5DC0>], 'identity': None, 'zones': None, 'extended_location': None, 'managed_by': None, 'etag': None, 'hardware_profile': <azure.mgmt.compute.v2023_09_01.models._models_py3.HardwareProfile object at 0x00000177654B5D00>, 'storage_profile': <azure.mgmt.compute.v2023_09_01.models._models_py3.StorageProfile object at 0x00000177654B5D30>, 'additional_capabilities': None, 'os_profile': <azure.mgmt.compute.v2023_09_01.models._models_py3.OSProfile object at 0x00000177654B5D60>, 'network_profile': <azure.mgmt.compute.v2023_09_01.models._models_py3.NetworkProfile object at 0x00000177654B5E80>, 'security_profile': None, 'diagnostics_profile': <azure.mgmt.compute.v2023_09_01.models._models_py3.DiagnosticsProfile object at 0x00000177654B5CD0>, 'availability_set': None, 'virtual_machine_scale_set': None, 'proximity_placement_group': None, 'priority': None, 'eviction_policy': None, 'billing_profile': None, 'host': None, 'host_group': None, 'provisioning_state': 'Succeeded', 'instance_view': None, 'license_type': None, 'vm_id': 'XXXXXXXXXX', 'extensions_time_budget': None, 'platform_fault_domain': None, 'scheduled_events_profile': None, 'user_data': None, 'capacity_reservation': None,
'application_profile': None, 'time_created': datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 21, 16, 0, 35, 641020, tzinfo=<FixedOffset '+00:00'>)}

How do I extract time_created?

Comment: Resolved it.
Quite simple, but I should have read the Microsoft documentation properly.
vm.time_created was all that was needed to extract the date.